# Little question about pattern matching of x_^n_

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm now practicing pattern matching by implementing a self-defined differentiation operator.

```
ClearAll[diff]
diff[fx_ + gx_, x_] := diff[fx, x] + diff[gx, x]
diff[c_*fx_, x_] /; FreeQ[c, x] := c*diff[fx, x]
diff[x_^n_., x_] /; FreeQ[n, x] := n*(x^(n - 1))
```

I test it with

```
diff[9^a, x]
diff[3, x]
```

But these two expressions do not further evaluate to the "correct" result. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of the two examples you show, neither of them matches any of the `diff` patterns you declared:

- In the case of `diff[9^a, x]`, note that your last pattern (`diff[x_^n_., x_] /; FreeQ[n, x]`) requires that the base of the first argument and the second argument both be `x`, so `diff[x^a, x]` or `diff[9^a, 9]` would match, but not `diff[9^a,x]`.
- In the case of `diff[3,x]`, you have no form of `diff` that matches on a single value in the first argument; you'd need something like `diff[q_,x_]` possibly with a requirement like `diff[q_?NumericQ, x_]`. This case does not match your third `diff` declaration either because 3 is not `x`.

Comment: Oh, I see! I was too focusing on `^n_.`, thinking it is the place where the problems arose. Thanks for the help.